# Application.Run - Workbook Name from Cell Reference - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, reference, cell

I am an amateur VBA user, trying to get by with various tutorials and trial-and-error so far.

At the moment I have met an obstacle with Application.Run. The Macro I have is working, I just need the Name(the date) of the workbook to update based on a cell reference containing a specific date.

as part of a longer Macro I may have one of the below depending on the workbook i am working in:

```
   Application.Run ("'09. September - Monthly Reconciliation.xlsm'!CombineTabs")
 or
   Application.Run ("'03.09.2016 - Daily Reconciliation.xlsm'!CombineTabs")
```

To prevent having to update the Macro daily or monthly *(it will be used by someone without any VBA knowledge*), **Is there a way I can link the name of the Workbook to a cell?** This cell would contain the name of the workbook, with the desired date and date format.

Any input appreciated,

Comment: Not quite sure of your question, but in a cell, you can use a formula to get the workbook name: `=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("[",CELL("filename",A1))+1,FIND("]", CELL("filename",A1))-FIND("[",CELL("filename",A1))-1)` - in VBA, you could do the same then parse out what you don't need.  OR are you asking how to get a variable to update, so you can have say `Application.Run(myDate&"- Daily Reconciliation.xlsm'!CombineTabs")`?

Comment: If you're not capturing a function's return value, or if you're calling a `Sub` procedure, [do not use parentheses around the arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/1179/procedure-calls/3818/this-is-confusing-why-not-just-always-use-parentheses#t=201609151902369636814) - this *will* eventually bite you in the rear end.

Comment: `Application.Run Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value`, put filenane to `A1` cell on `Sheet1`.

Comment: In the cell there will be a formula establishing the the name of hte workbook, including the date/date linked from another cell. (Basically just updating the date in the filename based on a date in the workbook) - What I need isfor the part of the "Application.Run" where I reference the name of the workbook the macro is pulled from, I want it to take the name in the cell rather than me having to write the name in the Code.

Comment: Just to clarify, is the macro located in the same workbook as this code?

Comment: yes, the macro is in the same workbook as the code

Comment: omegastripes:  I tried                                                                            Application.Run Worksheets("Sheet19").Range("AQ27").Value, !CombineTabs    - it just opens the other workbook but stops at the macro saying "subscript out of range".

Comment: @omegastripes the unqualified/global `Worksheets` collection implicitly refers to `Application.ActiveWorkbook`, which may not be the workbook containing the `CombineTabs` macro.

Comment: At this stage of the Marco, the Active workbook is one opened by the macro in the background, and not the one containing the Macro I want to run (CombineTabs). The CombineTabsMacro is located in the workbook the working macro is activated from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *yes, the macro is in the same workbook as the code*

If that's the case and I understand correctly, then you can simply do this:

```
Application.Run "CombineTabs"
```

Or even:

```
CombineTabs
```

---

> *I tried Application.Run Worksheets("Sheet19").Range("AQ27").Value, !CombineTabs - it just opens **the other workbook** [...]*

If the `CombineTabs` macro is located in *the active workbook*, which is **not** necessarily the workbook that contains the calling code, then you can do this:

```
Application.Run "'" & ActiveWorkbook.FullName & "'!CombineTabs"
```

---

If the `CombineTabs` macro is located in *some* workbook that isn't opened, and the file name is in the *same* workbook that contains the `Application.Run` instruction...

First, avoid hard-coding ranges and cell references; name the range `Sheet19!AQ27` with a workbook-scoped `Name` - call it something meaningful, say `Filename`. Then you can do this:

```
Application.Run "'" & ThisWorkbook.Range("Filename").Value & "'!CombineTabs"
```

Tested with this code in `Module1`

```
Public Sub Test()
    Debug.Print "yup"
End Sub
```

And this code in the *immediate pane*:

```
Application.Run "'" & Application.Workbooks(1).FullName & "'!Test"
yup
```

So, this assumes the `Filename` range contains a valid path+filename to an existing workbook.

You can verify this before trying the `Application.Run` call, by opening the target workbook yourself:

```
Dim target As Workbook
On Error Resume Next
    Set target = Application.Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Range("Filename").Value)
    Err.Clear
    If target Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
On Error GoTo 0
Application.Run "'" & target.FullName & "'!CombineTabs"
```

Comment: First: Thank you Mat! what I am trying to do is to go to my daily or Monthly Reconciliation Workbook, run a Macro that will open a separate Workbook in the background and run a Macro in it that is located in the the Monthly Reconciliation workbook i originally opened. When trying to implement suggested changes everything works fine up until i the second workbook is open and made the "Active Workbook". This is where it stops as the Macro I want to run is not located in this workbook but the one that is now inactive.

Comment: @kankuroo okay, you're very confusing. If `CombineTabs` is located in the same workbook that contains the `Application.Run` call, then see the top part of this answer - you don't need `Application.Run` at all. I'd suggest you make the `CombineTabs` procedure take some `Workbook` object as a parameter (and so instead of calling `Application.Run` you go `Application.Workbooks.Open` and pass the resulting workbook object to your macro), so you can work off an object reference instead of relying on whatever is active.

Comment: Sorry Mat, I am a little confusing at times. But You, you are a genius! I was under the impression I had to state which of the open workbooks contained the second macro I wanted to run in the newly opened workbook, and I over complicated it.  Your first suggestion of getting rid of the entire Application.Run line and replacing it with just CombineTabs works beautifully. Thank you for your help!!